# Postgres crosstab: function returning record called in context that cannot accept type record

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-functions, crosstab

I'm attempting to use the postgres [crosstab](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/tablefunc.html) function which states that the query passed in must return 3 columns:

> This statement must return one row_name column, one category column, and one value column.

However, when I run this query, I get the following error:

```
select crosstab('select entity_id, keyword_id, keyword_id from entity_keyword ORDER BY 1,2');
```

> ERROR:  function returning record called in context that cannot accept type record

I've played with the datatypes (in my case the 'value' doesn't matter - it's just true/false) but can't quite tell what the complaint is about.  The resultset of that query appears to me to conform to what's required.  Using postgres 9.2.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that `select crosstab` should have been `select * from crosstab`.